Short SF story with a 'post-form' society, where people can choose their human form and reform whenever, leading to more nuance in identity
I'm looking for the title of a short SF story with a 'post-form' society, where people can choose their human form and reform whenever, leading to more nuance in identity.
I read it in 2004, unsure of the publication date. It might be by a local Alaskan author (my teacher loved those).
It's a short story, maybe 2–5 pages, possibly in an anthology.
The story centers on a politician who uses a device on their spaceship to reform their body to any age, sex, or ethnicity. This is common, and public speakers use their form to match their intention or goal, leading to conversations on interconnections in perspective and identity.
It's not really political and doesn't have a 'point'. It just imagines a post-physical-form-restricted society and what that might mean for our physically restricted assumptions and values.

You've put 'post-form' in single quotes. Is term taken this directly from the story?

Sheffield wrote about "purposive form change" in his Proteus books, but I don't beleive this story is part of those.

Vague resemblance to the setting of John Varley's "Eight Worlds" stories, but I don't recall one that matches the politician-in-space story line. The closest might be a description from the Boss Tweed story line in  " The Ophiuchi Hotline" (1977 novel).  Perhaps a few pages of that was excepted somewhere?
